# Open a specific tab on a page from an external link (from an page)

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

This question has been asked a couple of times. I have tried out all the code snippets posted with regard to this issue, but nothing seems to work on my code. Here is a gist of how I have laid out my page elements:

1) I have a vertical tabbed list of products created on a page (e.g: Conveyors.html)

[image]

2) The tabs/products have ids of their own. When clicked on the tab or tab link in the same page (i.e. Conveyors.html.), the specific tab opens.

3) I have a main products page (Products.html) with links to all sub-products.

```
<a href="Conveyors.html#screw-content">
```

4) When clicking on a particular link on Products.html to open a specific tab on Conveyors.html, I am redirected to that page, but the tab does not open.

How to make a specific tab open when accessing from a different page.

a) Bootstrap method did not work

b) The tabs was not creating using Jquery UI tabs.

Please help me resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: So what jQuery you are using for Tab

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: // JavaScript Document
$(function(){
  $('#sidemenu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      // do nothing because the link is already open
    } else {
      var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
      var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');
      
      $(oldcontent).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(newcontent).fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
        $(oldcontent).addClass('hidden');
      });
      
     
      $('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
});

Comment: Ok no problem.I am giving you a way follow that.

Answer (score 0):

1) write in Dom ready

```
window.location.hash
```

this will give you **#screw-content**

2) Make condition and apply click/any operation to open Tab as per **hash** (#) value found.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: check for window.location.hash if it has value then you need to open that tab ok?

Comment: then write $('#sidemenu a[href="#ABC"]').click() here #ABC is the value you got from window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

Html on Main Page:

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href='Products.html'><span>Products</span></a>
 <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='Conveyors.html'><span>Converyors</span></a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="Conveyors.html#screwcon-content"><span>Screw Conveyors</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="Conveyors.html#beltcon-content"><span>Belt Conveyors</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="Conveyors.html#idler-content"><span>Idler Rollers</span></a></li>
             <li class='last'><a href="Conveyors.html#rollerpulley-content"><span>Rollers and Pulleys</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='BucketElevators.html'><span>Bucket Elevators</span></a>
                                <ul>
                                   <li><a href='BucketElevators.html#beltbucket-content'><span>Belt Type</span></a></li>
                                   <li class='last'><a href='BucketElevators.html#chainbucket-content'><span>Chain Type</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class='has-sub'><a href='OtherProducts.html'><span>Other Products</span></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href='OtherProducts.html#grindingmills-content'><span>Grinding Mills</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href='OtherProducts.html#feeders&screens-content'><span>Feeders & Screens</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href='OtherProducts.html#crushers-content'><span>Crushers</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href='OtherProducts.html#kilns-content'><span>Kilns</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href='OtherProducts.html#airslides-content'><span>Air Slides</span></a></li>
                                    <li class='last'><a href='OtherProducts.html#classifier-content'><span>Classifier</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


Html for Conveyors.html
<div id="products-verticalbar">
        <h1> Conveyors </h1>
        <ul id="sidemenu"> 
            <li> <a href="#screwcon-content" class="open">Screw Conveyors</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#beltcon-content" id="tab1">Belt Conveyors</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#idler-content">Idler Rollers</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#rollerpulley-content">Rollers and Pulleys</a> </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="conveyor-content">
            <div id="screwcon-content" class="contentblock">

            <p>A screw conveyor or auger conveyor is a mechanism that uses a rotating helical screw blade, called a "flighting", usually within a tube, to move liquid or granular materials. They are used in many bulk handling industries. Screw conveyors in modern industry are often used horizontally or at a slight incline as an efficient way to move semi-solid materials, including food waste, wood chips, aggregates, cereal grains, animal feed, boiler ash, meat and bone meal, municipal solid waste, and many others. The first type of screw conveyor was the Archimedes' screw, used since ancient times to pump irrigation water.</p>
            <img src="IMAGES/Screwcon.jpg"/>
            </div>

            <div id="beltcon-content" class="contentblock hidden">
            <p>A conveyor belt is the carrying medium of a belt conveyor system (often shortened to belt conveyor). A belt conveyor system is one of many types of conveyor systems. A belt conveyor system consists of two or more pulleys (sometimes referred to as drums), with an endless loop of carrying medium—the conveyor belt—that rotates about them. One or both of the pulleys are powered, moving the belt and the material on the belt forward. The powered pulley is called the drive pulley while the unpowered pulley is called the idler pulley. There are two main industrial classes of belt conveyors; Those in general material handling such as those moving boxes along inside a factory and bulk material handling such as those used to transport large volumes of resources and agricultural materials, such as grain, salt, coal, ore, sand, overburden and more.</p>
            <img src="IMAGES/beltconveyor.jpg"/> 
            </div>
            <div id="idler-content" class="contentblock hidden"> </div>
            <div id="rollerpulley-content" class="contentblock hidden"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

Script:
$(function(){
  $('#sidemenu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      // do nothing because the link is already open
    } else {
      var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
      var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');

      $(oldcontent).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(newcontent).fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
        $(oldcontent).addClass('hidden');
      });


      $('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can get var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
     with  window.location.hash

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  hashValue = window.location.hash;

  if(hasValue!=undefined && hashValue!="")
    {
      $('#sidemenu a[href="'+hashValue +'"]').click();
    }
  
  $('#sidemenu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();       

    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      // do nothing because the link is already open
    } else {
      var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
      var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');

      $(oldcontent).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(newcontent).fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
        $(oldcontent).addClass('hidden');
      });


      $('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Parth: No it does not work. Now the existing tab navigation in the same page is also not working.

Comment: It doesnt throw any error. But the side navigation functionality isnt working in the Conveyors.html page. But when i click on any product or its subproduct from products main page, it still takes me to the conveyors.html-screw conveyor tab.

Comment: Please put alert in if(hasValue!=undefined && hashValue!="") condition as it goes to that condition or not.